# In Swift, how do you check if an object (AnyObject) is a String?

Tags: string, swift

Tried using:

```
obj.isKindOfClass(String)
```

But it says Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'

So how can you tell if an object is a string or not?

The context of this question is the UIActivity method, prepareWithActivityItems, in which I need to save the activity item, but if there are multiple activity items, how do you figure out which is which?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Check:

```
obj is String // true or false
```

Convert:

```
obj as? String // nil if failed to convert
```

Optional binding:

```
if let str = obj as? String {
    // success
} else {
    // fail
}
```

Comment: That was easy. Right in the documentation too. Oops. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-XID_513

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to go off on a bit of a tangent so you understand what is going on.

**Strings are not objects in swift.    !!!**

Kinda. **???**

Because of the way toll-free bridging works... if you import the Objective-C runtime then you can treat strings as an object... check this out:

This code will not compile at all:

```
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play

// import Foundation

var foo: AnyObject = "hello"
                     ^ Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'
```

But if I uncomment the Foundation framework, then it compiles perfectly fine, because we're activating bridging between String and NSString:

```
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Foundation

var foo: AnyObject = "hello" // We're all good here!
```

And if you want to check if foo is a string... you can do this:

```
import Foundation

var foo: AnyObject = "hello"

foo.isKindOfClass(NSString) // this returns true
```

So... string is not an object but if you treat it as one it will be converted into an `NSString` and now it is an object. But you can't check if an object belongs to the `String` class, because there is no such thing as a `String` object. You have to use `NSString`.

Of course, you should still be doing what Scott said in his answer, by using the `is` or `as?` keywords.